# SSH Tunnelling - Remote Debugging

Tags: eclipse, remote-debugging, ssh-tunnel

I can ssh into the server say abc.xyz on port 22 but i can't remote debug it in Eclipse. Here is the additional info :

Server startup arguments -

```
-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1234,server=y,suspend=n
```

Confirmation from logs -

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 1234
```

When I telnet on my local system -

```
local-machine% telnet abc-xyz 1234
Trying xx.xx.xx.xx...
telnet: connect to address xx.xx.xx.xx: Connection timed out
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

When I telnet on the server(abc.xyz) -

```
abc-xyz% telnet localhost 1234
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

I've tried setting up tunnel via -

1. `ssh -L 1234:localhost:1234 user@abc-xyz`
2. `ssh -L 1234:127.0.0.1:1234 user@abc-xyz`

I'm attaching debugger in Eclipse with this config -

```
Connection type - Standard (Socket attach)
Host - localhost
Port - 1234
```

Can't get Eclipse to attach to 1234.

After setting up SSH Tunnel, if i manually try to connect to the port, i get this response -

```
local-machine% telnet localhost 1234
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.localdomain (127.0.0.1).
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

and I see an entry in catalina.out as:

> channel 4: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT - 1:**

I ran

```
abc-xyz% ~#
```

and got the following output:

```
The following connections are open:
  #2 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 fd 7/8 cc -1)
  #3 direct-tcpip: listening port 1234 for localhost port 1234, connect from 127.0.0.1 port 23456 (t4 r1 i0/0 o0/0 fd 10/10 cc -1)
```

I think ssh tunneling is working, it's just the way i'm connecting with Eclipse which is going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to increase timeout. (Can be done via Window->Preferences->Java->Debugging. Set it to some appropriate value.)